# Testing apn_sender gem with APN.notify()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, apple-push-notifications

I am trying use the apn_sender gem in a rails app to send iOS push notifications.  I have my my development push notification certificateSo in config/certs (named apn_development.apn), have a redis server running, and started the worker daemon.  I am trying to get a push notification sent to my phone for testing using the rails console.

After booting the console I try the following:

```
APN.notify('8987987...', :alert => 'New Message', :badge => 4, :sound => true, :other_information => 'value')
```

The console always returns true - yet I get no push notification.  I tried adding spaces between the token as follows and still get return of true but no result.

```
APN.notify('098d9d0s 09d9sdk 9alskdjf9 098d9ddj a767cd41 e2cfd6f8 57179e59 a767cd41 ef9dd62f', :alert => 'New Message', :badge => 4, :sound => true, :other_information => 'value')
```

When I try to get feedback, I use the following in the console:

```
apn = APN::Feedback.new
```

but I get the return:

```
#<APN::Feedback: Connection not currently established to feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com on 2196>
```

When I check the logs for the apn_sender I see that the worker is waiting and listening but never processes the push.  Output:

```
Registered signals
Checking apple_push_notifications
Sleeping for 5.0 seconds
resque-1.20.0: Waiting for apple_push_notifications
```

Etc...

Should I be attempting to place the APN.notify() code in a file and running it as a test or is something else wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: did you find any solution for this? me too facing the same problem. Please let me know, if you had figured this out.